# CakePHP trouble linking data from 2 tables in models

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am having trouble with linking data like first name from the table Users in the view of chats using cakePHP. Below is my code and whatever I do, the script does not select the user_id from the chats database table to display the first name. I must be overseeing something, but the loop I'm thinking in is giving me some headaches. Can someone please get me out of this loop?

User.php

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Ondutylog',
        'Chat'
        );
}
?>
```

Chat.php

```
<?php
class Chat extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User'
        );
}
?>
```

ChatsController.php

```
<?php
class ChatsController extends AppController {
    var $uses = array('User', 'Chat');
    public function view() {
        $chats = $this->Chat->find('all', array(
            'order' => array('id' => 'ASC'),
            'recursive' => -1
            ));
        $this->set('chats', $chats);
        $id = $chats['Chat']['user_id'];
        $userdetails = $this->Chat->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => $id
                ),
            recursive' => -1
            ));
        return $userdetails;
    }
}
?>
```

view.ctp

```
<?php 
foreach($chats as $chat) :
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$userdetails['User']['firstname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$chat['Chat']['user_id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$chat['Chat']['text']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$chat['Chat']['created']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
endforeach 
?>
```

The array I get returned in $chats

```
[Chat] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 11
        [text] => hello
        [created] => 2014-05-21 19:56:16
        [modified] => 2014-05-21 19:56:16
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need charge the model in your controller

```
class ChatsController extends AppController {

    public function view() {
        $this->loadModel('User');
        $this->loadModel('Chat');
        $chats = $this->Chat->find('all', array(
            'order' => array('id' => 'ASC'),
            'recursive' => -1
            ));
        $this->set('chats', $chats);
        $id = $chats['Chat']['user_id'];
        $userdetails = $this->Chat->User->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'id' => $id
                ),
            recursive => -1
            ));
       $this->set(compact('userDetails'));  
    }
}
```

Comment: Error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) for the lines loadModule

Comment: Tried this, but cannot get it to work :( get error in indefined index $id

Comment: $id = $chats['Chat']['user_id'];  <- here is not present a id, do you can show me  the array of data, because the reason of the error is that $chats not giving the value that is in the array,  and update the answer

Comment: Hi Widrogo, I have updated the question with the array I get returned in $chats

Comment: ok I can't see the problem, because you are usign an array of data you need foreach for obtain the valor of chats, but should be so $id= $chats[0]['Chat']['user_id']; -> if you want the first id in the array, but I can not see the numbering of array data for obtain the first value

Comment: Thanx for your help Widrogo. As you may have noticed I already have a solution. Added it as an answer here

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return $userdetails;
```

to

```
$this->set(compact('userDetails'));
```

You are supposed to set the view var not return the info.

Though why are you making a separate query for it instead of just using `'recursive' => 0` which would get the associated user record through table join and you can just use `$chat['User']['firstname']` in view.

Also get rid of `var $uses = array('User', 'Chat');`. It's not needed. `$this->Chat` is already available and the User model is accessed through association as `$this->Chat->User` as you have already done.

Comment: When I follow the last part of your reply I get:
SQL Query: SELECT `Chat`.`id`, `Chat`.`user_id`, `Chat`.`text`, `Chat`.`created`, `Chat`.`modified`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`firstname`, `User`.`lastname`, `User`.`email`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`passwordreset`, `User`.`picture`, `User`.`company`, `User`.`adminrole`, `User`.`onduty`, `User`.`lastlogin`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `c0captainslog`.`chats` AS `Chat` LEFT JOIN `c0captainslog`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Chat`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC

Comment: And if I use $this->set(compact('userDetails')); how will I be able to use the details returned?

Comment: I am sure you can figure out how to use an array yourself :)

Comment: Sorry in this case I can't as the array is returned OK, except it does not find the matching array from the user table

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and it's closer than I thought of myself. Because the Models User and Chat were already joined I just had to use a couple of lines in the Controller. So I modified it like this:

```
public function view() {
    $chats = $this->Chat->find('all');
    $this->set('chats', $chats);
}
```

And nothing more...